# Why pods aren't rescheduled when the remote kubelet is unreachable

Tags: kubernetes

I'm currently doing some tests on a kubernetes cluster.
I was wondering why the pods aren't rescheduled in some cases :

- When the node is unreachable
- When the remote kubelet doesn't answer

Actually the only case when a pod got rescheduled is when the kubelet notify the master.
Is it on purpose ? Why ?
If i shut down a server where there's a rc with a unique pod running, my service is down.

Maybe there's something i misunderstood.

Regards,
Smana

Answer (score 4):

There is a quite long default timeout for detecting unreachable nodes and for re-scheduling pods, maybe you did not wait long enough?

You can adjust the timeouts with several flags:

- node-status-update-frequency on the kubelet (http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/kubelet.html)
- node-monitor-grace-period and pod_eviction_timeout on the kube-controller-manager (http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/kube-controller-manager.html)

Comment: see a discussion about this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-containers/xoohw81bIPw/cnxEGluuCmEJ

Comment: Thank you, i'll test these settings :)